# Associations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am developing a web application for task management using ruby on rails. 
I have two models `user` and `task`. The models look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def role?(role_name)
    role == role_name
  end

  def self.assigned_user(task_params)
    User.where("name = ?", task_params["assigned_to"])
  end
end



class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

what i want is assign task to user when a task is created. But i don't know how to do it in `create` action of `tasks_controller`. My create action looks like this

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        @user = User.assigned_user(task_params)
        @user.tasks << Task.last
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Whenever admin assigns a task when its created, it gives an error saying `undefined method tasks for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe7b1c60610>`. Does anyone can help what can be the problem with this?

Comment: What's this? `@user = User.assigned_user(task_params)` Also in the next line use this: `@user.tasks << @task`, otherwhise it will do a query in database unnecessarily.

Comment: assigned_user is method in User model, which returns the user retrieved from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error it is giving you is because the `where` method is returning a collection of users and you want just one user:

```
def self.assigned_user(task_params)
  User.where("name = ?", task_params["assigned_to"]).first
end
```

You probably want to revise your code as I guess you could have problems if `name` is not unique. Make sure the field you use to retrieve the user is unique.

The code for creation can look like this:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      @user = User.assigned_user(task_params)
      @user.tasks << @task
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @user is not assigned yet. It gives the error 'undefined method tasks for Nil class'.

Answer (score 0):

Well the *error*, speaks for itself:

> undefined method tasks for User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe7b1c60610>

```
def self.assigned_user(task_params)
    User.where("name = ?", task_params["assigned_to"])
end
```

`where` method returns an `array`(*ActiveRecord_Relation*), then since you need only to fetch one object, it shoud be:

```
User.where(name: task_params["assigned_to"]).first
```

or even better:

```
User.find_by(name: task_params["assigned_to"])
```

Also this line:

```
@user.tasks << Task.last
```

Will do a query in database unnecessarily.

So it should be changed to:

```
@user.tasks << @task
```

Hope it helps!!